# How to post multiple JSON files to a server using cURL

Tags: json, curl

I have multiple JSON files within a folder and I would like to post them all at once, in a single command line using curl. Is there a way to do this?

I have these files within a folder in my directory..

```
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(1).json
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(2).json
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(3).json
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(4).json
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(5).json
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(6).json
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(7).json
20190116_101859_WifiSensor(8).json
```

... plus more

I'd like to post all of the files from the folder in one go.

I know how to post one file using

```
    curl -d "@20190116_101859_WifiSensor(1).json" http://iconsvr:8005/data
```

I need a way of posting them in one go, without having to write out each file name, if possible.

Comment: note: I'm using windows command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a foreach loop to iterate over all files in your current directory which contains *WifiSensor* in the filename.

In **Linux (Bash)** you could use

```sh
for f in *WifiSensor*.json; do curl -d $f http://iconsvr:8005/data; done
```

In **Windows (CMD)**

```
for /r %f in (*WifiSensor*.json) do curl -d %f http://iconsvr:8005/data
```

Don't forget if you using the **Windows** Snippet above in a Batch file, you need to double the % signs.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just a side note, I had to add curl -d "@%f" http//...  for it to work with my files.